# some questions about SQLite in phone programming

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I'm developing an app using database in iPhone.
So I studied a little to use database.

Today, I made a table and executed below code.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idxRegionNum on City ( RegionNum );
```

And I got a syntax error.
I explored internet, I thought that NONCLUSTERED syntax doesn't exist in SQLite.

But I need to use NONCLUSTERED INDEX.
So I tried to make some indexes, and they were made.

I studied that clustered index can exist only one a table.

In SQLite, does 'create index idxRegionNum on City ( RegionNum )' make nonclustered index?

Thank you for your reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, SQLite indexes are non-clustered.

The only exception that I know of is when you’re using an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY field in your table; that will use the table’s internal row index as primary key.

See [this post](http://osdir.com/ml/db.sqlite.general/2003-07/msg00101.html) for a bit more info.